# Which resources teach spectrum analysis of NMR and IR spectra?

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, reference-request, books, ir-spectroscopy

I’m looking for a textbook that can teach me NMR and IR spectrum reading and analysis.

I really don't understand how to read the spectra or how to analyse them.

Comment: Try Oxford Chemsitry Primers, specifically for NMR I recommend Peter J Hore's book, called Nuclear Magnetic Resonance (I have the second edition)

Comment: Depends on what you want. PJ Hore's primer focuses mainly on the physical principles of NMR. For application of NMR, IR, MS etc. to organic molecule identification I would go with Tim Claridge's primer *Introduction to Organic Spectroscopy*.

Comment: If this question is off-topic, [this one](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303) must be too. (However, this could be a dupe of that.)

Comment: @Jan I agree. The main resource thread certainly doesn't have spectroscopy recommendations, though. I will edit some in when I'm free then close as a dupe.

Comment: Hesse, Meier, Zeeh, *Spektroskopische Methoden in der OC*. Very good German book, covers all NMR, IR, MS that the ordinary organic chemist needs. There is an english translation available.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense without knowing your background. Student, professional? Biology, engineering, physics? I guess you're not a chemistry student?

Answer (score 0):

I found Oxford Chemistry Primers to be quite good. There are many topics and the books themselves are very thin, but provide an adequate amount of information for undergraduate level.

Comment: [Introduction to spectroscopy]
Donald L Pavia; author.   How about this book??  is it good???